# How Short URL works?

Tags: short-url

I'm thinking of implementing a short/friendly URL system in my company.

I've read a lot of articles describing how to do it. I understand the process but I still have some questions: we have server A and client B. Server A has all the logic for URL rewriting and redirecting. But how can Client B, external to that server but in the same domain, know what is the hostname or IP for http://server.A/theURL? If the name of "server.A" is not known for the client it'll return an "unknown host" error. How can you "publish" that short url "domain" in the network? I don't think you have to modify the .hostname files of every single PC...

Thanks,

Comment: your server will do a permanent redirect (301) and the client gets that information from that initial request.  *this assumes the client has access to that server - aka not behind a firewall, etc*

Comment: yeah, but how does the client know that the short url belongs to that server. there should be a mapping of "short.url" to that server. how do you do that?

Comment: The mapping is done through the server A as you said in the post.  Once the short URL is translated to the real one, it sends that URL to client B and then client B connects as normal.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining myself clearly. If I try to go right now to "short.url/asdfasd" my browser will say "Unknown host". How can my PC know the IP or real hostname of "short.url". It has to be in a DNS server or something. But if it's in an intranet how do you do it?

Comment: Yeah that's why my first comment said "aka not behind a firewall, etc".  If that's the case, you're going to use a reverse proxy.  Most any web servers can do this but I prefer [nginx](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-reverse-proxy/).  It'll just make the outter server (server A) communicate on behalf of anyone trying to get to short.url (like how client B is doing).  client B will never know the real IP/hostname of short.url since it will only see server A on the outside

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to point the vanity domain url to goo.gl. Then request a url from goo.gl shortener using my google API key then I str_replace the url with my vanity url and output that as the final solution.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using (free) APIs from major url shortening services:

BITLY https://dev.bitly.com (most known)

CLICKMETER http://clickmeter.com/api (best analytics)

GOO.GL https://developers.google.com/url-shortener (simple)

OWLY (integrated with HootSuite)

REBRANDLY https://developers.rebrandly.com (use your domain name)

SHORTE.ST https://shorte.st/howitworks (monetize clicks)

Comment: The idea was to understand how it works and implement it myself, not just use an external service.